# append text to Args[] in Rscript

Tags: r, args

It might be naive but finding hard to solve.Here is sample R script to plot A vs B.

```
Args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
A<-c(1:10)
B<-c(2:11)
png(Args[1])
plot(A,B)
dev.off()
```

It is executed as : `Rscript plot.r pic`

1.I would like to add a png file extension to the Args[1]. i.e. the output file should be pic.png.

2.Is there a way to give path to write the file to Args[1]?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Write in the png part:

```
png(paste(Args[1], ".png", sep=""))  # => "pic.png"
```

Similarly, you can put a path before the args argument:

```
PATH = "/example/path"
```

As [flodel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201032/flodel) mentioned, `file.path` ensures not having to worry about forgetting an ending `/`:

```
file.path(PATH, paste(Args[1], ".png", sep=""))
```

Comment: I don't see what you mean. If you set PATH (or just fill it in directly), it pastes it correctly together, as long as you have `sep=""`?

Comment: Note that in R >= 2.15 there is the `paste0` function which is just paste but uses sep='' by default.

Comment: @flodel I am not sure what the topic starter wants, but if he sets PATH manually he could simply include the `/` right?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `paste`, I often use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%s.png", Args[1])
```

here the `%s` is replaced by the content of `Args[1]`.